# How to build Android application in Centos from command line

Tags: android, command-line

I have a Centos 6 server without graphics screen. Now I need use Centos server to build existing Android application source without using Eclipse.

I installed Android SDK from http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.3-linux.tgz

Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you trying to build the Android or just an application for Android?

Comment: I have source code android (developed in window). Now I need to build (compile) it on Centos and get *.apk file. That's all

Comment: See [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way that comes to mind is to install x and foward over ssh. Then build as any other directions would advise.